# Generate database schema from Typescript interfaces

Tags: javascript, database, typescript

I'm trying to generate a schema based on the AWS SDK interfaces. We're trying to build a inventory of all resources over multiple accounts. These API call's give me a lot of JSON, and I need an easy way to store that in a relational database.

So my question is can I generate a SQL database schema (for postgresql or mysql) based on interfaces without adding entity annotations (those are needed for typeorm for example).

Answer (score 0):

Typescript interfaces are not present at runtime. They help during development and compile(yes, I know it is transpile) time checks.

There could be an approach that may help you with the task.

**Option 1:**
The easiest way is to put your classes to implement the interfaces. By doing so, you ensure you haven't missed anything:

Example:

```js
@Model()
export class MyDbModel implements TheAwsInterface {
}
```

**Option 2:**
Store the AWS response as a single JSON serialized object as a bson or string column in the database.

**Option 3:**
The other option is to implement a static interface parser and model generator yourself. A very basic sample follows. The sample does not work with nested objects, and it cannot identify which one is the primary key column. But with some effort and configuration, it may be extended.

[Playground link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dijfsu?file=index.ts)

```js
const inputInterface = `
interface AwsUser {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
}
`;

enum SupportedTypes {
  'string' = 'string',
  'number' = 'number',
}

type ParsedInterfaceResult = {
  interfaceName: string;
  props: Record<string, SupportedTypes>;
};

const removeNewLines = (input: string): string => {
  return input.replace('\n', '');
};

const extractInterfaceName = (input: string): string => {
  return input.substring(0, input.indexOf('{')).replace('interface', '').trim();
};

const parseInterfaceProps = (input: string): Record<string, SupportedTypes> => {
  const result = {};

  const props = input
    .substring(input.indexOf('{') + 1, input.indexOf('}') - 1)
    .split(';');

  props.forEach((prop) => {
    if (prop.trim() === '') {
      return;
    }
    const [key, value] = prop.split(':');
    result[key.trim()] = value.trim();
  });

  return result;
};

const parseInterface = (input: string): ParsedInterfaceResult => {
  const sanitizedInput = removeNewLines(input);
  return {
    interfaceName: extractInterfaceName(sanitizedInput),
    props: parseInterfaceProps(input),
  };
};

const convertToTypeOrmModel = (
  interfaceDefinittion: ParsedInterfaceResult
): string => {
  const lines: Array<string> = [
    'import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm"',
    '',
  ];

  lines.push('@Entity()');
  lines.push(`export class ${interfaceDefinittion.interfaceName} {`);

  Object.keys(interfaceDefinittion.props).forEach((propName) => {
    lines.push(`  @Column()`);
    lines.push(`  ${propName}: ${interfaceDefinittion.props[propName]};`);
    lines.push(``);
  });

  lines.push('}', '');

  return lines.join('\n');
};

const result = parseInterface(inputInterface);

const generatedCode = convertToTypeOrmModel(result);

/*
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm"

@Entity()
export class AwsUser {
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  age: number;

  @Column()
  address: string;

}
*/
```